# How to insert a popup modal without creating unnecessary white space?

Tags: html, css

Here's the situation: I want an element to appear on top of a link when a user clicks on that link. Right now, I have a div element located at the bottom of the page, which I hide when the document loads using Jquery. I have the link working so when the link works, the element appears on top of the link. I am able to put the element on top of the link by positioning it relatively. The problem is, when I use Jquery to show the element, white space appears at the bottom of the page. I presume that the white space is supposed to be for the div element if it wasn't positioned. Is there a way to do this without the extra white space showing where the element would be if it hadn't been positioned?

Here is the code for the element:

```
#confirm-delete {
  position: relative;
  top: -200px;
  width: 400px;
  z-index: 1000;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
}
```

Nevermind, I solved it. I set the outer container to be positioned relative, and I set my #confirm-delete to be positioned absolutely.
Thanks.

Comment: You would probably save a lot of time just using something like jqueryui for dialogs.  it's super easy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try using `position: absolute;` instead of relative, if you want to position something on top of another

Comment: the reason i think this might work is: "an absolutely positioned element is removed from the normal flow" -read more here: http://www.alistapart.com/articles/css-positioning-101/

Comment: If I do that, I guess I would have to set the containing div element to position: absolute?

Comment: maybe you want the container relative, depending on what that is, could you show us the html? A quite normal approach is to have the overlay (modal) element positioned with values you set with jquery - i.e. find the position of the element you clicked on, and append the overlay div directly in body element with absolute positioning with top and left values that match the position of the clicked element.

Comment: This didn't work for me, as I want my dialog to size to fit the contents and an absolute positioned div will not enforce a size on the containing dialog.